# Order varchar column with numbers and other non alphabetic characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **mysql** table that contain a column storing time squences like this:

08:00 - 09:00
09:00 - 10:00
07:00 - 08:00
11:00 - 12:00
06:00 - 07:00
... and so on.

When making a **mysql** query I would like the result to be ordered by this column which, by the way, is a **varchar** data type column.

The result I want is:

06:00 - 07:00
07:00 - 08:00
08:00 - 09:00
09:00 - 10:00
11:00 - 12:00

This is what I´m trying without success:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY CAST(mycolumn AS INT) ASC;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of your column by the string value produces the results you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY mycolumn ASC;
```

The numbers are zero-padded on the left, so they sort the same way as strings and as integers.